# Call Python script on request - Python server

Tags: python, server, python-requests

I want to be able to call a python script by making a request on a Python server I created from [this tutorial](https://www.junian.net/2014/07/simple-http-server-and-client-in-python.html)

I want that when the server receive a particular request, it launch the Python script.

I tried this simple code without success. I thought that on `GET` request it will launch the `externalFunc.py` script. But it does not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os

#Create custom HTTPRequestHandler class
class KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

#handle GET command
def do_GET(self):
    execfile("root\externalFunc.py")



def run():
   print('http server is starting...')

#ip and port of servr
#by default http server port is 80
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler)
print('http server is running...')
httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
run()
```

I dont have any error, just nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : Here is the GET request made by the client :

```
import sys

#get http server ip
http_server = '127.0.0.1'
#create a connection
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(http_server)

#request command to server
conn.request('GET', '','')

#get response from server
rsp = conn.getresponse()

#print server response and data
print(rsp.status, rsp.reason)
data_received = rsp.read()
print(data_received)

conn.close()
```

And I got a 501 error from the server :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2018 15:46:46] code 501, message Unsupported method ('GET')
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2018 15:46:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

Comment: Without seeing `root\externalFunc.py` there is now way to know. The `do_GET` handler must send an answer to the request. I don't think  `root\externalFunc.py` does that for you. Why do you use `execfile` anyway?

Comment: You are right, maybe i don't use the good functions. What I want to do is simple : I want to launch a Python script on any request, wether it's GET / POST / Whatever..

Comment: did you try in web browser `http://127.0.0.1:80` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the python code you've posted is broken, if you did copy&paste
from your own script, then your code is invalid python because the indentation
is wrong.

Secondly, it's a bad idea to just execute a script with `exec`, this can be dangerous,
specially if you are not the owner of the script and how knows what the script
does.

So let's modify your `root/externalFunc.py` first: let's add a `run` method that
does the work of the script. Instead of just printing to the standard output,
the `run` function should return something, for example the a string or a
dictionary containing the results.

Because you haven't shown us the code of `root/externalFunc.py`, I assume that
the script may look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# root/externalFunc.py
# old version

def run():
    # ... doing some work,
    # result is a variable with the result
    print "Result: %d" % result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now let's modify it.

1. create an empty file `__init__.py` in the `root/` directory:

   ```
   // on linux/mac/bsd
   $ touch root/__init__.py

   // on windows
   cmd> type NUL > root/__init__.py
   ```

This allows to use `from root.whatever export something` in another module.

2. Let's add a `run` method that actually does the work:

The new version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# root/externalFunc.py
# new version

import sys

def run(parm1, param2, param3):
    # ... doing some work,
    # result is a variable with the result

    return = {
        "success": True,
        "value": result
    }

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print >> sys.stderr, "usage: %s param1 param2 param3" % sys.argv
        return 1
    param1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    param2 = sys.argv[2]
    param3 = int(sys.argv[3])

    res = run(param1, param2, param3)
    if res["success"]:
        print "Result: %d" % res["value"]
        return 0
    else:
        print "Error, ..."
        return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return main()
```

Now we have to change your server code to import the `run` method and use that
method instead of using `exec` or `execfile`

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from root.externalFunc import run as externalFunc_run

class KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        param1 = 3
        param2 = "max"
        param3 = -12

        res = externalFunc_run(param1, param2, param3)

        if res["success"]:
            answer = "The result is: %d" % res["value"]
        else:
            answer = "Error while computing externalFunc"

        #send code 200 response
        self.send_response(200)

        #send header first
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

        # send answer
        self.wfile.write(answer)
```

Now if you don't want (or cannot) change the code of `root/externalFunc.py`, or the script
is not a python script, then you could use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```
import subprocess
import shlex

# bad, don't do that
# exec("root/externalFunc.py")

# do this instead
answer = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("root/externalFunc.py params..."))
print "Answer: %s" % answer
```

Using `subprocess.check_output` is much more safe, behind the scenes it calls
[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), which executes a child program in a **new process**,
thus the child program won't cause damage if it goes bersek.

Now you can replace this line `res = externalFunc_run(param1, param2, param3)`
with the `subprocess.check_output` line.

Comment: Really thanks for your help and your time, I really appreciate it. Alright I see how it could works now. I still have one problem : When I try to send a `Get` request from a client script, I receive an error  `Unsupported method ('GET') error 501`. Why is that ?

Comment: @thib I don't know, I don't use `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, I usually use tornado. I'll take a closer look later. The error message is probably an exception, at which part of the code did you get that?

Comment: Many thanks. I got it when posting my GET request  : `http_server = '127.0.0.1'
#create a connection
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(http_server)
#request command to server
conn.request('GET', '','')
#get response from server
rsp = conn.getresponse()`

Comment: @thib is this on the server script or the client script?

Comment: This is the request made by the client, on the server I didnt changed the do_GET method you wrote.

Comment: @tlb, ok, this seems to be a client problem then. Can you edit your question and add the client code + the whole exception in your question?

Comment: @thib I made copy&paste from your code (with a simplified `do_GET` that always returns a string) and I didn't get this error, my client got a response. See https://pastebin.com/KQWKeW5d

Comment: well I will dig into it to find the fault cause on my computer. But the code code seems to work so this is good, thanks you !

Comment: now it works so this great. But I have an additional issue : when I send the request the server put itslef in "TIME_WAIT" and then stop listenning the port. How could I do to make it listen all the time ?

Comment: @thib great that you got your code working. But please create a new thread with your new questions, the comment section is not a good place to start asking more questions.